# How do I create this table with a xsl template?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml:

```
  <plot>
    <image>1.png</image>
  </plot>
  <plot>
    <image>2.png</image>
  </plot>
  <plot>
    <image>3.png</image>
  </plot>
  <plot>
    <image>4.png</image>
  </plot>
  <plot>
    <image>5.png</image>
  </plot>
```

I need to show a table with 3 columns and if last column (column #6) not exist, I need to put '---',
like this:

```
| col_a | col_b | col_c |
--------+-------+--------
| 1.png | 2.png | 3.png |
| 4.png | 5.png |  ---  |
```

How do I create this table with a xsl template?

Comment: Are you actually looking for fixed width text output like that or is your example just a representation of an HTML table or similar?

Comment: Just a representation of an HTML table. Please ignore the table header. I need to show only images in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over every third plot element, and have each iteration output all cells for the row, like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="plot[position() mod 3 = 1]">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::plot[1]">
          <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::plot[1]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>---</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::plot[2]">
          <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::plot[2]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>---</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you want a solution that scales to any number of columns, do the same sort of loop, but instead of explicitly doing each column, call a template that outputs a cell and recursively calls itself with the remaining number of cells to output.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably utilize the [xsl:number count](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_number.asp) attribute to find the number, see if it's divisible by 3, figure out how many ----s you need

Then use a [foreach](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp) to loop through the elements and add in the correct number of -----.